# Is there a way in vim to know I am in the left most split?

Tags: vim

I want to detect whether or not I am in the right most (or left, top, bottommost) split. In other words, when `ctrl-w h` would do nothing. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's only `winnr()`, which is a sequential numbering; i.e. you can only check for topleft- and bottomright-most window, but not the exact window relations. If you need this information in a mapping / script, you'd have to do exactly as you've described:

```
function! IsLeftMostWindow()
    let curNr = winnr()
    wincmd h
    if winnr() == curNr
        return 1
    endif
    wincmd p " Move back.
    return 0
endfunction
```

EDIT: winnr('$') is a special case which returns the highest index in the current tab. So if winnr() == winnr('$'), you're on the bottomright-most (or the only) window.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using split screens in `vim`, you will see in the bottom of all of the split screens a bar with the filename (and information about the position of the cursor). In the active window, the text in this bar bold-face. So by checking the bold-face text, you can immediately see which of the splits you activated.

Comment: I hope this is enough information, or is there a reason to have automatized detection?

Comment: I was referring to from vimscript, I know how to tell which pane I'm in with my eyes :)

Comment: @AaronJensen I couldn't tell from your question, but you got a perfect answer anyhow :)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is `win_screenpos({nr})`.

To test if window 3 on the leftmost, `if win_screenpos(3)[1] == 1`.
To test if current window on the topmost, `if win_screenpos(0)[0] == 1`.